# Easiest way to deploy / access JAR dependencies separately on wildfly

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a website that's building as a WAR.  The entire WAR is 100MB, but 73 MB of that consists of jar files maven has included as dependencies.  I realize I could install all of them as modules in Wildfly, but that would require configuring the server for over 100 files and maintaining the unholy mess when dependencies are updated.

In the interest of not having to wait 5 minutes to publish the updated WAR, what is the easiest way to deploy this massive collection of JAR files separate from the application and still retain access to them from the application?

Comment: First Maven does not include dependencies on its own. Those files are part of your dependencies which means your dependency have dependencies of their own (so called transitive dependencies)...Furthermore the question is what kind of dependencies those are? May be have packaged dependencies which might not really needed? Furthermore why does it take 5 minutes to deploy a 100 MiB war file(remote deploymet)? Maybe you can show the pom file..If you separate the WAR and the other files you think into the modules of Wildfly you have to maintain them separately..(other git repo?)

Comment: These are just standard dependencies.  Spring, Hibernate, Dozer, etc.  I suppose I could just glom them up into a separate user library, deploy it separately as a Wildfly module, and mark the dependency "provided" in my Pom.  I just wasn't sure if that's the easiest way.

Comment: As far as why it takes 5 minutes to deploy a 100MB war, the work is contract and the provided laptop is a bit of a dog running a VM. 

Comment: First Hibernate is a JPA implementation which is provided by Wildfly (as far as I know) which means you don't need it to deploy it with your WAR file...and not needed to put that into the modules area...Spring and Dozer is something different. I would prevent to separate things into Modules of Wildfly cause that makes you depend on Wildfly...apart from that I would reconsider about the usage of Wildfly may be better to use Spring-Boot and you have a single jar file as a result...but this is an other story...Furthermore why using a VM for that? Why no using a Docker container for such things?

Comment: I don't have any control over how the client images our laptops unfortunately. 

Comment: Why do you have hibernate in there since it is provided in WildFly ? Maybe you should trim those dependencies first.